# HHL algorithm, How to implement exp(iAt) gates?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hhl-algorithm, quantum-phase-estimation

From this paper [Quantum Circuit Design for Solving Linear Systems of Equations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51944125_Quantum_Circuit_Design_for_Solving_Linear_Systems_of_Equations), in figure 4
[image]

The paper shows what inside operator $e^{-iAt}$ but didn't shows how to connect the control qubit (register term C) how can I connect them?

Comment: Ask only a single question at once. However, you can likely re-formulate your question list to get an answer for 2 or more of your current points. It is also likely, that knowing the answer for that, you will know the answer for all.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: the question has been edited after I wrote my answer.*

---

A point by point answer:

> 1. The paper shows what inside operator $e^{-iAt}$ but didn't shows how to connect the control qubit (register term C) how can I connect them?

The problem of controlling a full circuit (or sub-circuit here) has a trivial solution: control all the gates that compose the circuit.

So the implementation of the **controlled** exponential operator will be performed via this kind of circuit:

[image: exponential circuit]

All you have left to do is to decompose the non-primitive gates into primitive ones such as CCZ -> H(2) CCX H(2) -> H(2) [Toffoli gate implementation] H(2).

> 2. How can I encode matrix A into the circuit? Is the circuit for operator $e^{-iAt}$ in fig 4 can be use for any 4x4 matrix?

The matrix $A$ is already encoded in the circuit. In fact, the circuit implements the unitary matrix $e^{-iAt}$ which is the only place in the HHL algorithm where we actually need $A$.

As far as I know, this circuit *may* be able to encode any $4\times 4$ matrice. I do not think this is the case, but I do not have counter example to provide so the possibility is still there.

> 3. What does the eigenvalues from matrix $A$ is for? How is it related to the circuit?

In HHL and in linear system solving in general, the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ are a particular interest. In this case, HHL works by estimating the eigenvalues of the matrix and *inverting them* (as in $\frac{1}{\lambda}$). In this paper, the authors use this specific matrix with these specific eigenvalues because the eigenvalues are easy to encode on qubits and the inversion step is easy to implement.

---

Some quick notes about this paper and the implementation:

1. I studied quite a lot this paper and even implemented it. The code is available [here](https://github.com/nelimee/quantum-hhl-4x4).
2. The last `Z` gate in the implementation actually seems to be an error. At least I was not able to make the code work with this `Z` gate but I was able to get results when replacing it with a `CZ` gate.
3. It is important to realize that this implementation is **highly** tailored to a specific matrix $A$. Changing it to make it work with another matrix $A$ will require to re-write nearly everything from scratch.

Comment: Could you tell me the value  of $t_0$ in your implemented code? I try to implement my own version but got different result.

Comment: My $t_0$ is $2\pi$ like in the article: https://github.com/nelimee/quantum-hhl-4x4/blob/master/hhl4x4/optimise_parameters.py#L110